# How to select item in autocompletetextview programmatically

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I`ve got a trouble closely related with autocompletetextview behaviour. 
In my app I use AutoCompleteTextView instance as usual:

```
textViewCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textCountry_Edit);
mCityCursorAdapter = new CityCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
textViewCountry.setAdapter(mCityCursorAdapter);
textViewCountry.setThreshold(1);
```

Everything is fine, when I begin input symbols I will receive Dropdown with the list of countries, then I select one of the country and this country name appears in EditText and DropDown is dismissed.
But when I rotate device (my activity don`t re-create, I noticed it in manifest) Dropdown appears again and I had to confirm my choice again. Is there any way how to avoid this repeatedly action?

Edit#1:  It will be fine if I`m able to simulate item selection from dropdown list programmatically something like performClick... Another way to solve my problem is (as I think) at the right moment switch adapter off and then at the proper time switch it on but it needs to find a proper time in fragment lifecycle.

Edit#2: I noticed different behaviour AutoCompleteTextView depending on devices. Everything is ok on Nexus7, Samsung Note 2, but Motorola Xoom has wierd behaviour as I described above.

Comment: try amit gupta solution

Comment: I guess your manifest still needs to be edited

Answer (score 1):

Try using two methods in your `Activity` class

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration confi) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(confi);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) doesn`t be called in my case... I tried in onConfigurationChanged inserting textViewCountry.setAdapter(null);
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);  
textViewCountry.setText(country);
textViewCountry.setAdapter(mCityCursorAdapter);  but it doesn`t help